# Ember site breaks if I insert link to nested outlet

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm learning ember at the moment and I'm having some trouble.

I've got this nested outlet that I want to link to, but when I do, nothing works and i get an "Uncaught Object object" on handlebars.js:704.

I can go to the correct view by typing the url in (looks like this: index.html#/google/systemet) but if I do the following i get the error.

```
{{#linkTo 'systemet' this}}Systemet{{/linkTo}}
```

Now, I'm really unsure about how to use ember. Fact is that I don't know it at all. I don't get why I'm typing 'this' in the end of the link and I'm quite sure that that is why the site breaks. I'm just starting this project out, so here's my complete app.js:

```
APItest = Ember.Application.create();

APItest.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('google', function() {
    this.resource('systemet', { path: '/systemet' });
  });
  this.resource('overlook');
  this.resource('discogs');
  this.resource('songkick');
  this.resource('lastfm');
});

APItest.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function () {
        this.transitionTo ('overlook');
    }
});

APItest.GooglesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return "hero";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on the code surrounding the `linkTo`, `this` may be used to pass a model to a route that expects a dynamic segment. your "systemet" route, however, *doesn't* expect a dynamic segment, so you don't need `this` in this case.

apart from that, you may or may not need to create an `APItest.SystemetRoute` (i'm still getting confused as to what ember generates automatically and what not.^^)

*p.s.: in case you haven't found them yet, here are the ember guides for [defining routes](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) and [linking](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/).*

Comment: Thanks for the comment Finn, but sadly enough this didn't get me anywhere closer. Still looking through the guides though!

Comment: could you maybe post the template with the `linkTo` in it, then?

Comment: Hey man. This is kind of embarrassing, but i found the solution. the first T in my linkTo in my code wasn't capitalised. I'm going to put myself in the corner for a while, thanks for your help either way.

Comment: np. it happens to the best of us.